# Can slugs from posts and custom post types conflict?

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect, slug

I have a system built on WordPress where we're using several custom post types, and I'm seeing some weird behaviour.

For instance, I have a CPT called "Flyers", and I also have a CPT called "Templates". The Templates CPT has a post called "Flyers". In Flyers CPT I have a post called "Flyer 01".

Now when I try to $_POST to the Flyer 01 permalink (/flyers/flyer-01/) it looks like WordPress is redirecting my request to Templates post called Flyers (/templates/flyers/).

Does anyone have any good ideas on what's going on here? And how do I get it to stop doing that redirect?

Comment: I recently came across the same issue. Yes, they do conflict. WP only checks the slug for uniqueness against others of the same type.

Comment: Is there any way to prioritize them?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could try rearranging your permalink structures. I didn't try it myself mind.

Comment: I sorted it out by intercepting the $_POST via an init hook, before any redirection or rewrite rules are effectuated. It's a nasty dirty hack, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are using `POST` method, so url is **not** visible (and search engines don't take is into account), send the request using **query string**:

```
add_query_var( array('post_type' = 'flyers', 'post_name' = 'flyer-01'), home_url() );
```

In this way the url generated is something like `http://example.com?post_type=flyers&post_name=flyer-01` is ugly to see, but no one have to see it... and it works (it should).